# Maximal planar graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, connectedness, planar-graphs, triangulation

A maximal planar graph $G$ with at least 3 vertices is a simple finite planar graph for which we cannot add any new edge $e$ such that $G \cup e$ is still planar. Is there an easy and rigorous way to prove that such a graph is connected (between every 2 vertices there is a path)?

I know that such a graph is a plane triangulation. But I don't wish to use the fact that this means $G$ is 3-connected since it seems overkill. I also know there's an intuitive argument where I look at the "face with the disconnected components" and "add an edge within it connecting them". Is there a way to make this rigorous (using topological facts like in [Diestel](http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf)) or maybe a better proof?

Comment: Erm... which "connected" are you referring to...

Comment: @user21820 I've edited the question!

Comment: are you assuming that these are graphs with a finite number of vertices?

Comment: @Charlie Yes, I've edited the question again.

Comment: @Charlie: That's very interesting. Is there an infinite maximal planar graph that is not graph-connected?

Comment: @Charlie: Someone and I just found the answer to my question. Consider the graph that has a vertex for each point $(x,y)$ where $x$ is rational and $y$ is an integer and an edge between adjacent points with the same $x$ coordinate. This graph is a **countable** graph that is embedded into a plane but is disconnected into **infinitely many** components! If you want a graph that has **some** embedding into a plane but has no proper containing graph with a planar embedding, I think using reals instead of rationals, and then Zorn's lemma, but I'm unable to get it.

Comment: @user21820 very cool example!  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Charlie: A fairly intuitive example is to start with the planar graph consisting of the edges of a tiling of the plane by equilateral triangles. Take the origin as one of the vertices. Now shrink radially by (for instance) the map $r\mapsto\tan^{-1}r$; the result is a $6$-regular maximal planar graph $G$ on countably infinitely many vertices contained within the circle of radius $\pi/2$ centred at the origin. No vertex of $G$ is accessible from outside that circle, so the union of countably infinitely many pairwise disjoint copies of $G$ is maximal planar but with cnt. inf. many components.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for this example, it is neat to see how my argument below fails in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easy to make your intuitive argument precise.

Suppose towards a contradiction that each $G$ is a disconnected but maximal simple finite planar graph with components $G_1$ and $G_2$ for simplicity.  Since $G$ is maximal, each $G_i$ must also be maximal.

We fix a specific planar embedding of $G$.  First, pick any planar embedding of $G_1$ and call its image $G_1'$. The boundary edges of $G_1'$ form a simple closed curve since $G_1$ is maximal, so they divide the plane into two regions, one of which is unbounded. Call this region $O_1$. Now pick a planar embedding of $G_2$ into $O_1$, and let $G'_2$ denote the image.  Define $O_2$ similarly to $O_1$ and note that $G_1' \subset 0_2$ and $G_2' \subset O_2$.

Now since $G$ is finite, $O_1 \cap O_2$ must be path connected as each $O_i$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a compact set removed. The closure of $O_1 \cap O_2$ contains a vertex $v_i$ of $G_i'$ by construction, and there is a path $e$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$.  Adding this path as an edge to $G'$ yields a planar graph, contradicting the maximality of $G$.

Comment: Thanks! But what if $O_2$ lies inside one of the triangles of $O_1$? Then $O_1 \cap O_2$ might not be path connected in $G'$? [(diagram)](http://postimg.org/image/cx2b922cx/)

Comment: Good catch. But notice that since your graph is disconnected, you can choose your embedding so that this doesn't happen. I'll elaborate in my response.